# Display a random thumbnail on facebook

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook, meta

I'm looking for a way to make my website to display a random thumbnail (from a list of images) on facebook, when its displayed on commentaries or posts

By now, i know that the thumbnail and information displayed is defined by that code:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="[url to image]" />
<meta property="og:title" content="[page name]" />
<meta property="og:description" content="[content description]" />
```

So, is there a way to make the og:image select randomly from a list?

Comment: Not really - Facebook caches the OG meta data. Sure, you could clear the cache regularly - but that is not really a good idea either, pretty sure that will lead to problems sooner or later. Plus, users refreshing the share attachment on the post they made later will get to see a different image - confusing.

Comment: Hi AcidSys, Did you already solve this? I am almost 1 week working just for this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script to add all the images' URLs to an array and then use script again to select a random URL from the array to be displayed.